# How to classify unlabelled data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

I am new to Machine Learning. I am trying to build a classifier that classifies the text as having a url or not having a url. The data is not labelled. I just have textual data. I don't know how to proceed with it. Any help or examples is appreciated.

Comment: You can add the new column for label in your data as simple as 1 and 0 for those contains and does not contain. If you are using pandas dataframe to read data and need a column , you may have to provide more details.

Comment: You need labelled data to teach a classifier. How else should it know that you're interested in text having or not having urls, and not in texts talking about flowers vs. texts talking about ponies? However, since URLs have fairly standard formats, you can add training labels automatically with a small program.

Comment: Having a URL and not having a URL? A URL has a well defined format, you can just use Regular Expressions to identify if the text has something that matches this format. You don't need AI for such simple task.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's text, you can use `bag of words` technique to create vectors.

- You can use `cosine similarity` to cluster the common type text.
- Then use classifier, which would depend on number of clusters.
- This way you have a labeled training set.

  - If you have two cluster, binary classifier like logistic regression would work.
  - If you have multiple classes, you need to train model based on multinomial logistic regression
  - or train multiple logistic models using `One vs Rest` technique.
- Lastly, you can test your model using k-fold cross validation.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot train a classifier with unlabeled data. You need labeled examples. There are services that will label it for you, but it might be simpler for you to do it by hand (I assume you can go through one per minute).
2. Stack Overflow is for programming; this question would be better suited in, say, [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Maybe they'll have better suggestions than me.
3. After you've labeled the data, there's a lot of info on the web on this subject - for example, [this blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/automated-text-classification-using-machine-learning-3df4f4f9570b) is a good place to start if you already have some grip on the issue.

Good luck!